# Did the sort order for Campaign change recently?

Tags: civicampaign

I help a group that has a lot of Campaigns and they report that things are sorting differently after a recent update. It used to sort alphabetically when creating a new contribution, but now it sorts by Campaign ID in reverse order (newest first).

Did this change recently, and if so, is it possible to change it back in a setting?